# Why my bottom sub-component is shown on top of a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jqvkqy29w) environment to show an issue.

Basically the problem is when I click "Option 1" in a main menu, a new component appears in which a bottom sub-component (called `BottomControls.js`) is showed in the top of a page instead of a bottom of a page.

Also the `CardContent` is white instead of `backgroundColor: 'rgb(225, 0, 80)'` as defined in `styles.js`.

It seems like styles are applied incorrectly in `BottomControls.js`. I passed styles as a parameter to `BottomControls.js` from a parent component `Main.js`.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main issues with how you were trying to use your styles:

- You weren't exporting anything from `./layout/single/styles.js`
- You weren't using `withStyles` to convert the JS object into CSS classes that you can use

Here's a CodeSandbox that fixes those main issues:

[image: Edit 1z9qk10rj4]

Changes to `Main.js`:

```
// added
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

Changed `export default class extends Component`
to `class Main extends Component`

```
// added to end of Main.js
const StyledMain = withStyles(styles)(Main);
export default StyledMain;
```

Changed cases of `mystyles={styles}` to `mystyles={this.props.classes}` (the `classes` prop is injected by `withStyles`).

Then in `styles.js` I added `export default styles;` to the bottom.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!